# Correct Android Emulator for Nexus 7 2013?

Tags: android, emulation

The Android emulator for a Nexus 7 (2013) doesn't seem to run at 1200 X 1920

The "Device Pixel Ratio" is reported as 1.3, whereas the actual device reports 2.0

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try genymotion. It is an absolutely awesome and fast emulator. You can even run google play services on it and use push notifications etc..

Here is the [link](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: Do you work there? The free version doesn't do "Pixel Perfect" according to the site...

Comment: No am just a developer who uses it everyday!! The free version works just fine. It is the best emulator that I have seen till date. Try it out and you will say the same thing!

Comment: Thanks, yes its much more accurate!